# Is having onClick set to null on a <button/> a bad practice in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm creating a custom Button component in react.js. I was wondering if having onClick={null} on a HTML button would create unnecessary event listeners that I don't need?

```
<button value="test" onClick={onClickHandler} onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}/>
```

I would use this technique if that is the case:

```
<button value="test" {...(onClickHandler && {onClick:onClickHandler})} {...(onSubmitHandler && {onSubmit:onSubmitHandler})}/>
```

Comment: `undefined` is normal in this case, but `null` should work too

Comment: Why bother adding `onClick={null}` to the button? What do you hope to achieve? Also typo: `onClickHanlder`.

Comment: @andy [updated the post]. I'm passing the handler functions as a prop. And I'm using null as a default prop so my aim is not to create unnecessary listeners when the handlers are null.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to make the button unclickable after a certain event, just make sure its disables after that event.

```
<button value="test" onClick={null} disable={valuable onevent here set it to true} />
```